# Queue multiple requests from SL4 app to a service

Tags: silverlight-4.0, asynchronous

I have several pseudo-global entities in my Silverlight application that are populated with data from the server.  My 'service agent' class is registered with the IoC container as a singleton so it will cache the data to prevent excessive calls to the server.

However, I'm running into a scenario where multiple requests are being made to the 'service agent' while the initial request is still pending.  While I look into other design issues contributing to the situation, I'm wondering what ideas you may have how to handle this.  My initial thought is to somehow queue the requests if a call is already in progress then handle them when the data is retrieved.

Comment: More details are needed here.  Sounds like a design issue to me.  Why are multiple requests been made whilst the initial request is pending?  Why not set some kind of flag/lock to prevent further requests until the initial one has completed?  Can you provide a few basic code snippets?

Comment: The most concrete would be our application settings which we need to pull down from the server to initialize some functionality.  Multiple views (ergo viewmodels) will attempt to asynchronously load the settings from our singleton service agent; however, I don't want to make multiple calls. I'd rather have only the first request translate into a service call then have all others suspend until the call returns at which point I can trigger all of the callbacks.

Comment: Yep I think you are heading in the right direction with a queue and lock mechanism.  Have a read of this post for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465442/how-to-run-batched-wcf-service-calls-in-silverlight-backgroundworker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the queue and lock approach after all.  I have a 'busy' flag that indicates a service call is in-progress.  When true, all subsequent requests are queued by adding the callback delegate to a collection and the method returns. When the async service call returns, I simply iterate through the collection and execute each callback.  It seems to work pretty good (in an async model).